Creating a Calculated Column on PowerBi
I'm looking to create a Calculated column on PowerBi. The output I require is named as RequiredOutput.
Your assistance please..



ID
Date
OldStatus
NewStatus
RequiredOutput




12345
30/09/2021


Self


12345
31/10/2021


Self


12345
30/11/2021
Self
Team
Team


12345
31/12/2021


Team


12345
31/01/2022
Team
Self
Self


12345
28/02/2022


Self


56789
30/09/2021


Team


56789
31/10/2021


Team


56789
30/11/2021
Team
Self
Self


56789
31/12/2021


Self


56789
31/01/2022
Self
Team
Team


56789
28/02/2022


Team




Could you specify the rule behind the RequiredOutput column ?

Power Query
Via Power Query, you can group by ID, then fill-up OldStatus and fill-down NewStatus, then create a new column based on NewStatus ?? OldStatus.
let
  Source = YourTable,
  #"Replace to null" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source, "", null, Replacer.ReplaceValue, {"NewStatus", "OldStatus"}),
  #"Grouped rows" = Table.Group(#"Replace to null", {"ID"}, {{"Rows", each _, type nullable table[ID = nullable text, Date = nullable text, OldStatus = nullable text, NewStatus = nullable text]}}),
  #"FillUp OldStatus" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped rows", { "Rows", each Table.FillUp(_, {"OldStatus"})}),
  #"FillDown NewStatus" = Table.TransformColumns(#"FillUp OldStatus", { "Rows", each Table.FillDown(_, {"NewStatus"})}),
  #"Add Status" = Table.TransformColumns(#"FillDown NewStatus", { "Rows", each Table.AddColumn(_, "Status", each [NewStatus]??[OldStatus]) }),
  #"Expanded Rows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Add Status", "Rows", {"Date", "Status"}, {"Date", "Status"})
in
  #"Expanded Rows"

DAX
You can also try the following in DAX, though depending on your data model size, you may experience slower refresh times:
Status = 
  var thisID = [ID]
  var thisDate = [Date]

  var filterPrev = 
    FILTER(
      'YourTable',
      [ID] = thisID && [Date] >= thisDate && NOT ISBLANK('YourTable'[OldStatus]) && 'YourTable'[OldStatus] <> ""
    )
  var filterNext = 
    FILTER(
      'YourTable',
      [ID] = thisID && [Date] <= thisDate && NOT ISBLANK('YourTable'[NewStatus]) && 'YourTable'[NewStatus] <> ""
    )

  var prevStatus = CALCULATE(MAX('YourTable'[OldStatus]), TOPN(1, filterPrev, [Date], ASC) )
  var nextStatus = CALCULATE(MAX('YourTable'[NewStatus]), TOPN(1, filterNext, [Date], DESC) )

  RETURN COALESCE(nextStatus, prevStatus)

